# Disadvantages of installed packages (other than disk space use and file system "clutter")?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, system-installation

I'm asking cause I've got a bunch of devices (ARM as well as x86 / AMD64), and I'm thinking of unifying the operating systems on them (for ease of management). I mean to install debian (stable or testing/sid is a bit of a tricky question - but not the one I'm asking here!), and I was wondering what disadvantages it would have to "simply" install the identical packages to all machines / keep the packages in sync across machines (I realise this might not work across architectures - this too is not my question here though..).

**So - beside the obvious "waste" of disk space, and the added nodes on the filesystem** (and the increased messiness), **what disadvantages would this "syncing" of my installations have ?**

PS - just to round this off - the advantages I'd hope for are: ease of management (ie in the same vein as putting the same OS on all of the devices), and having any applications I use available on all systems (at the snap of a finger :P - ie without having to install manually at times).

Thanks (in advance), and looking forward to what people have to say!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some disadvantages I can think of are:

- conflicting packages: for example you are forbidden to install both `postfix` and `sendmail` on the same Debian system.
- Packages that start servers by default (like `ntp`). This will expose unnecessary servers on the systems that don't require those servers. Sure, you can disable them whilst leaving the package installed, but it seems riskier and more work.
- Lack of some packages under certain architectures preventing a fully unified installation — you've already thought of this one.
- Tight disk space on smaller (embedded?) systems can't accommodate all of the packages.

+1 to unified cookie-cutter system installations in general though!